# eclipse cannot update - no repository found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

Running eclipse luna 4.4.1 sr1, i cannot update or do anything to complete a successful update.  the error logs only show the exact same message i see in the gui - no repository found for a variety of packages (anything being checked for update).  I have tried the usuals, deleting/cleaning old update sites, checking/unchecking 'contact all sites...' in Install New Software.

this isn't just my home pc, its my work config as well, and they share not much in common so I'm pretty sure its core related.  What is going on and what can I do that will 100% work?  already lost a few days to this.  This is reminding me of the horrible eclipse 3 days :(

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled and added my plugins from scratch (marketplace) right over the same workspace.  Seems to work now.  (sigh)